# After upgrade: GWT 2.6.1 compiler fails with: Field has no 'addValueChangeHandler' method associated

Tags: gwt, uibinder

after having upgraded GWT from 2.5.1 to 2.6.1 in my application, I get several GWT compiler errors for a particular self-implemented composite widget.

For a view containing this widget it says:

```
Rebinding com.myapp.client.page.FilterPanel.Binder
  [java]          Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
  [ERROR] Field 'statusBox' does not have an 'addValueChangeHandler' method associated.
[ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/myapp/client/page/com_myapp_client_config_MyAppGinjector_MyappGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java'
```

The field is a generic suggest box containing a `TextBox` and a `DefaultMultiWordSuggestBox`

```
public class SuggestValueBox<T> extends Composite implements HasConstrainedValue<T> {
...

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<T> handler) {
        return addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

Thus, I would argue that the field has such a method.

It seems that the compiler only fails if the generic type `T` is an enum (the same view has also `SuggestValueBox<String>` instances which seems to be OK for the compiler.) The enum type is within the `shared` package.

I also found this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6091 which seems to be related but this should be fixed in the version I upgraded to.

Thanks,
Rainer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the origin of the problem - on my side actually.

The problem was that my view had several instances on `SuggestValueBox<T>` for various `T` but only a single `@UiHandler` method for all these instances for a single concrete type `T`

```
@UiHandler({"fieldForTypeA", "fieldForTypeB"})
public void onValueChange(@SuppressWarnings("unused") ValueChangeEvent<TypeA> event) {
    this.submit();
}
```

As you see, this worked before since I did not use the content of `event`.

Having a `onValueChange` for each concrete type `T` resolves this.

Comment: Actually, it worked before because matching was done with raw types, not because you didn't use the content of the event.

Comment: You are right. I should have said: I didn't care about the type because I did not use the argument anyway. ;-)